# Recurrent neural network for predicting power consumption

Tags: forecasting, recurrent-neural-network

I am working on my coursework project and would like to predict energy consumption by a building based on past energy consumptions. I am planning to use recurrent neural network(LSTM model) for this.

I am trying to model past energy consumption as a function of past indoor temperature, outdoor temperature and set point data.  So I'll be having 2 time-series data as inputs namely, (indoor temp - set point) and (outdoor temp - indoor temp) and compare output with the energy consumed at that time. I have not seen any example with 2 time- series datasets as inputs. I feel I am fundamentally wrong somewhere.I wish someone who worked on this can give me better insights. Any suggestion would be very helpful for my progress. Thanks a lot.

Aditya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually have to use a recurrent network, but rather try to ensure the range and scale of what you're feeding the network is optimal.  Thus, you might look at detrending by inputting the deltas of the x's and the y (energy usage) between each time point.  Also, look into use of a moving average over time because if the data are noisy, it won't help the function approximation.  It's not really the type of ANN you use as much as it is getting the appropriate range and scale of inputs to work.

Comment: Hi..Thanks for the reply. I am having a dataset which is consistent so I dont feel noise would be a problem. All I am concerned is that I haven't seen any example with two timeseries datasets as inputs to RNN. Can you please suggest an example which I can look in and understand how it works for multivariant inputs. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Look at the VantagePoint neural network package for inter-market equity price prediction.  This package exploits inter-market (between-market time series data) to model stock price prediction.  Neurodimensions (www.nd.com) also has a neural network for financial time series which allows dozens of recurrent models with multiple hidden layers (i.e., Elman-Jordan, etc.)